# How can i group by my data for the respected code

Tags: sas

## Group by specific carrier in carrier variable, which has different carrier names i want to group by specific carrier, after replacing missing values with mean of total_travel_time, arrival_delay.

```
proc stdize data=mydata.original_data reponly method=mean out=Complete_data;
var total_travel_time, arrival_delay;
run;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Please review your post and the guidelines here [ask] to updated your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat groups of observations separately then use BY group processing. Make sure the data is sorted first.  Also do not include comma in the VAR statement.

```
proc stdize data=mydata.original_data reponly method=mean out=Complete_data;
  by carrier;
  var total_travel_time arrival_delay;
run;
```

Comment: hi tom thanks for the suggestions, can you also show me how i can achieve the same results while using proc sql coalesce to replace missing with mean and then group by specific carrier for each missing value

Comment: Why would you want to uses SQL instead of the PROC?

Comment: Yes because, when i group by in this query the whole data is getting categorized by carrier, rather than i want to group missing value data by specific carrier so that each missing value is replaced by average missing value of each carrier which makes replacement with average specific to each carrier,

Comment: For eg for carrier x the missing value should be replaced by carrier x average value, not the entire columns average value.

Comment: If adding the BY statement to PROC STDIZE does not actually cause it to use the group means then post a small example dataset (2 groups with 3 to 5 observations each) into your question that demonstrates the issue.